# Linking to file in GitHub Readme makes gives a 404?

Tags: github, markdown

I've trying to have a link to a different file but the link leads to blob/master which 404's.

```
'Readme.md'
'1 Dir'/
  - 'File 1'
  - 'File 2'
```

I know spaces are not liked in File names but I'd prefer to keep it this way for the project. Forgive me.
In Readme I have `[link 1](/1%20Dir)` and I've tried `[link 1](/"1 Dir")` but the second didn't work and the first lead to `https://github.com/User/Repo/blob/master/1%20Dir` which returns 404.

I also have in File 1 `[link 2](/File%202)` and this does the same as above.
It seems that the links are not working relativity but everything I've found online has what I have and they say it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to use `./` like :

```
[Link](./File%20With%20Space)
[Link](./FilePath)
```

Seemed a little odd as I could reference an image like this :

```
![Image](Images/img.JPG)
```

Use `./` to start :)

Comment: Does this still work for markdown files? In my main md I have [My release](./releases/my-release.md) but when I visit the page, it gives a 404. The my-release.md file exists within a releases folder.

Comment: It is still working for me. Are you 100% sure the links are written correctly?